# How can I duplicate the Resnet50 to five branches?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

Below you see the network structure of the ResNet50. What I want to do is **duplicate the last convolution layers to five branches** for some spesific task, where each branch will consist of two FC layers. How can I do that in the Pytorch, where Resnet50 is already loaded as

`ResNet50 = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)`

[image]

Comment: Checkout its [source code](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/_modules/torchvision/models/resnet.html) and access the layers as you wish

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to index the children of the resnet model and then attatch a sequential after that pair of conv blocks. One great implementation can be found [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/branch-cnn-implementation-question/95009):

You can use this same principal to replace the vgg with your resnet.Play close attention to how they slice the model and then add a linear sequential.

```
class BCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BCNN,self).__init__()
        # Load pretrained model
        vgg_model = models.vgg16_bn(pretrained=True)
        self.Conv1 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_model.features.children())[0:7])
        self.Conv2 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_model.features.children())[7:14])
        # Level-1 classifier after second conv block
        self.level_one_clf = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(128*56*56, 256), 
                                           nn.ReLU(), 
                                           nn.BatchNorm1d(256), 
                                           nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                           nn.Linear(256, 256), 
                                           nn.BatchNorm1d(256), 
                                           nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                           nn.Linear(256, 2))
        self.Conv3 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_model.features.children())[14:24])
        # Level-2 classifier after third conv block
        self.level_two_clf = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(256*28*28, 1024), 
                                           nn.ReLU(), 
                                           nn.BatchNorm1d(1024), 
                                           nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                           nn.Linear(1024, 1024), 
                                           nn.BatchNorm1d(1024), 
                                           nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                           nn.Linear(1024, 7))
        self.Conv4 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_model.features.children())[24:34])
        self.Conv5 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_model.features.children())[34:44])
        # Level-3 classifier after fifth conv block
        self.level_three_clf = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512*7*7, 4096), 
                                             nn.ReLU(), 
                                             nn.BatchNorm1d(4096), 
                                             nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                             nn.Linear(4096, 4096), 
                                             nn.BatchNorm1d(4096), 
                                             nn.Dropout(0.5), 
                                             nn.Linear(4096, 25))     
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.Conv1(x)
        x = self.Conv2(x)
        lvl_one = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        lvl_one = self.level_one_clf(lvl_one)
        x = self.Conv3(x)
        lvl_two = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        lvl_two = self.level_two_clf(lvl_two)
        x = self.Conv4(x)
        x = self.Conv5(x)
        lvl_three = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        lvl_three = self.level_three_clf(lvl_three)
        return lvl_one, lvl_two, lvl_three
```